# How use startAt()?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

```
function Request(registrationToken, id) {
var ref = firebase.app().database().ref();
var attendees = ref.child('/Users/'+ registrationToken);
attendees.on('child_added', snap => {
    let user = ref.child('/Users/'+ registrationToken + '/' + snap.key + '/time');
    user.once('value').then(userSnap => {
        console.log(userSnap.val());
    });
} );}
```

Need get time more `1000000` with use function `startAt()`

Comment: Your question is not very clear. Don't see any startAt usage in your code.

Answer (score 1):

You can use it in combination with any `orderBy` method.

So let's say you want to use it to filter the `users` by name:

```
let user = ref.child('/Users/'+ registrationToken + '/' + snap.key + '/time').orderByChild("name").startAt("john");
user.once('value').then(userSnap => {
    console.log(userSnap.val());
});
```

Would return all `users` with the name `john`.

You can learn more [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/node/firebase.database.Query#startAt).